# Pandas installation in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I installed Spyder (without anaconda)

I wrote in the console

```py
import pandas as pd
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module
KeyError: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module
KeyError: 'pandas._libs.missing'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module
KeyError: 'pandas._libs.hashtable'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-15-38d4b0363d82>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "pandas/__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "pandas/_libs/__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module
KeyError: 'pandas._libs.interval'
```

I already tried in the terminal

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Try to install the module trough Spyder's own console by writing `!pip install pandas`

Comment: The following error appears : "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion"

Comment: What is your SPyder version?
What is your Conda version?
What is your pip version?
What operating system are you on?